# how to call a webservice using html and javascript

Tags: javascript, .net, mysql, web-services, html

I am creating a mobile website using html5. Currently i use javascript to populate my fields with static data. I have also created a webservice using .net and c#, and a database using mysql. My webservice can query the data base properly. Does anyone know how to call the webservice from a javascript function?

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would use jquery for it. There is a pretty good article about it here:
http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-consume-aspnet-json-web-services/

Basically, you call the webservice, with the Ajax() function, and hook up some functions to its success (and possible failed) events, like in this example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "RSSReader.asmx/GetRSSReader",
    data: "{}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
      // Hide the fake progress indicator graphic.
      $('#RSSContent').removeClass('loading');

      // Insert the returned HTML into the <div>.
      $('#RSSContent').html(msg.d);
    }
  });
});
```

You can then get your webservice output, from the "msg" in the sucess function.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is using [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) - most libraries like jQuery have direct support. Note that by design, browsers do not allow you to access a web service that's running on a different domain to the host page (see [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)) but there are ways round this using techniques like [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP).

The quickest way to get started is probably to use [jQuery's ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) function. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

- You can invoke your webservice using jQuery
  .http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/WCF_JQUERY_ASMX.aspx
- Or can use asp.net ajax
  http://dotnetspeaks.com/DisplayArticle.aspx?ID=100